# maven jenkins Random .java:[18,6] cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: class Test

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, mockito

I have a Jenkins build that behaves weirdly.I get:

```
    "[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
                [ERROR] location: class com...
                [ERROR] /location../.java:[26,6] cannot find symbol
                [ERROR] symbol:   class Test
                [ERROR] location: class com...
                [ERROR] /location../.java:[38,6] cannot find symbol"

Or sometimes I get:

[ERROR] symbol:   method assertEquals(int,int)
[ERROR] location: class com...
[ERROR] /location../.java:[54,6] cannot find symbol

Or:

[ERROR] symbol:   variable Mockito
... cannot find symbol
```

It's for various classes and various packages.

I should mention that the application is composed of multiple parent projects and multiple child projects for each of them.

I can normally get a couple of successful builds before that error shows up. 
If I run it in eclipse everything is fine and if I run it in single thread everything is fine i.e. 10 consecutive builds without issue. 
Any suggestions would be very welcomed thank you so much for your time guys.What I have as dependencies in the parent pom:

```
<dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.25</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.25</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-hamcrest</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <powermock.version>1.5.1</powermock.version>
        </dependencyManagement>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mina-filter-ssl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
                    <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-continuation</artifactId>
                    <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
                    <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
                    <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.19</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                    <version>14.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
                    <version>1.33</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.12</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>java-hamcrest</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                    <version>1.10.19</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
                    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
                    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>powermock-classloading-xstream</artifactId>
                    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
                </dependency>           
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.github.lukehutch</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fast-classpath-scanner</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.18</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guice-assisted-inject</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.6</version>
                </dependency>
                </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
```

I have been at this for days so anything even if it's just a guess...